# PATCH Issue - {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}

Tags: integration, callout, http, post, patch

I have a callout that is having an issue with it's POST. I have seen a couple of work arounds for this issue but none of them seem to work with my integration.

```
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override','PATCH');

or

adding "?_HttpMethod=PATCH" to the end of the endpoint
```

I continue to get the error:

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}

Before I move toward Heroku or MuleSoft, is there any other work arounds that I might not have stumbled across yet?

```
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    //request.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'PATCH');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('AuthToken', authToken);
    //request.setEndpoint(UPDATE_LEAD_ENDPOINT + '?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
    request.setEndpoint(UPDATE_LEAD_ENDPOINT);
    String requestBody = JSON.serialize(updatedLeadData);
    request.setBody(requestBody);

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    String responseBody = response.getBody();
    return '';
```

Comment: the endpoint you are referencing doesnt support the POST method, its not really an issue, its just not supported, did you check the api's documentation for supported methods?

Comment: Are you trying to use standard REST API endpoints to update a Lead?

Comment: yea the documentation states it can take a POST but it clearly isn't accepting it.

Comment: @JayantDas yes, I just put them in named credentials but they are standard URL endpoints

Comment: @Olivia `POST` is only for creating records, you will need to use `PATCH` here. I have added references from the docs in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from other alternatives, a [composite request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) would suffice. This method accepts a POST, and you can specify individual methods (like PATCH) for each of up to 25 requests. You'll just need to adjust the JSON to have this extra metadata.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to utilize the standard REST API endpoint to **update** a `Lead` record. If that's the case, then you will need to utilize a `PATCH` request here. `POST` is not supported request type for any update requests, it is utilized only for [creating records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm).

This is from [Update a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm) documentation:

> Provide the updated record information in your request data and use the PATCH method of the resource with a specific record ID to update that record.